# How to enable Microphone for Firefox Profile where Automation runs

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have my selenium runs on firefox with below settings on test profile which I have created manually .

```
 case "Firefox":
     FirefoxProfileManager profileManager = new FirefoxProfileManager();
     FirefoxProfile profile = profileManager.GetProfile("test");
```

Now I want to run my code with microphone settings enabled. For the first time I can go to that test profile and attach the headset and that will store the settings so when test will run next time it will pick up the same settings but problem is I have to attach the headphone to the machine, which I don't want to do as test might run on any of the VMs and if that will happen and no headset then test will break. So, how can I enable microphone setting without attaching the headset?

[image]

Comment: Try this `FirefoxProfileManager profileManager = new FirefoxProfileManager(); FirefoxProfile profile = profileManager.GetProfile("test"); profile.SetPreference("media.navigator.permission.disabled", "test");`

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro Thanks for solution. This works but problem is if any of the single firefox profile is open test wont run and my all tests are setup to run parallel. So rather then using "test" profile, how can i set above for any of the Firefox profile . Please help me to update the code.

Also initially my code was like below before using profile .

         case "Firefox":
                                    _driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                                    ConfigureDriver();
                                    break;

Comment: Since, `SetPreference()` is a method of `FirefoxProfile` class. Hence, you'll have to set it for every profile you have. Everytime you do a `GetProfile()`, you'll have to call the `SetPreference()` method.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro the code you gave me is actually remembering the option for Microphone to use always but it is not the way were we dont have to plug the headphone . I still have to plug the headphone. And getting message as screen grab in my question which i have updated. Please help me with it.